# Python Azure Event Hub Consume Event Properties

Tags: python, azure, properties

I'm struggeling to get the properties of events send to azure event hub using python. Currently I don't know how to consume additional event properties I send with a event message.

This is my code of sending messages which works great, BUT on the other hand I would like to consume those properties.

```
   event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch()
    i = 0
    while i <= 100:
        #json_obj = {"TimeStamp": str(datetime.utcnow()),"Name":f"Test{i}", "Metric":"11", "Source": "EventHubMessage"}
        json_obj = {"TimeStamp": "timestamp","Name":"Test", "Metric":11, "Source": "EventHubMessage"}
        string = json.dumps(json_obj)
        Event_data = EventData(body=string)
        Event_data.properties = {"Table":"TestTable", "IngestionMappingReference":"TestMapping", "Format":"JSON", "Encoding":"UTF-8"}
        event_data_batch.add(Event_data)
        i += 1
    print(event_data_batch)
    return event_data_batch
```

as you see, I'm sending additional event_data properties `{"Table":"TestTable", "IngestionMappingReference":"TestMapping", "Format":"JSON", "Encoding":"UTF-8"}` and those I would like to consume with another python application.

Can you please help me by letting me know how to do this? Currently, I'm just able to retrieve the body of the message but not its properties.

Maybe someone of you did already figure this out.

Thanks!

Best,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

In the receiving end of your application you can access the properties on the EventData object like this:

```py
event.properties
```

which prints:

```py
{b'Table': b'TestTable', b'IngestionMappingReference': b'TestMapping', b'Format': b'JSON', b'Encoding': b'UTF-8'}
```

If you are following the docs from MSFT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send then simply add this line under the first print statement to print the event properties:

recv.py:

```py
async def on_event(partition_context, event):
    # Print the event data.
        print("Received the event: \"{}\" from the partition with ID: \"{}\"".format(event.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8'), partition_context.partition_id))
        print(event.properties)
```

Additionally if you want to consume your properties dict as a dict of string key-value pairs (rather than bytes) you can decode it with a dict comprehension:

```py
{k.decode("utf-8"):v.decode("utf-8") for k,v in event.properties.items()}
```

which outputs:

```py
{'Table': 'TestTable', 'IngestionMappingReference': 'TestMapping', 'Format': 'JSON', 'Encoding': 'UTF-8'}
```